# Installing iperf without internet or c++ compiler

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I'm having a bit of a tricky problem installing Iperf. So the I need to install iperf on 2 remote boxes, The problem is that  these boxes do not have internet access. I can't install from the binary files as the boxes do not have a c or C++ compiler.

SO is there any way for me to get iperf on the machines with out installing a C++ compiler?

All machines are Ubuntu.

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 3):

are you installing it from source?

just download the .rpm or .deb (depending on distro) and manually install it.

or manually install the gcc compiler from the package file.

more info would be helpful, distro, how you are installing it etc.

Comment: Oh ye sorry, All machines are Ubuntu. I was trying to install it from the source and a .deb file but the .deb was giving me a: '-bash: dpkg: command not found'

Comment: did you run dpkg as sudo? `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`

Comment: Yes. To be clear What I'm hoping for is maybe some way of using scp to send some sort of iperf packet to one of the remote boxes that will let me install / run iperf on the machines. I'm not sure that this 'Magic' solution is possible.

Comment: @Paddy Yes, using the `.deb` should accomplish that.  Download from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=iperf) for the correct OS version and CPU architecture.  If `dpkg` isn't found then there's something wrong with either your path or your whole system - does `/usr/bin/dpkg` exist?